# ERROR: Tag must follow the pattern &#039;^:[a-zA-Z0-9_]([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]){0,127}&#039;

Tags: php, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I would like tag my docker php image with two tags: first with major php version and second with full php version, e.g. 8.1 and 8.1.10.
I get error:

> Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId:
> 11cbbfb3-43b5-4790-8082-4355ed6ababd Also:    Also:
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId:
> 1aaa7224-51a9-477c-94b0-ca65291b598d ERROR: Tag must follow the
> pattern '^:a-zA-Z0-9_{0,127}'

A problem is with using variable in agent docker. I don't want to use the image version directly because it loses the meaning of the matrix.

Part of Dockerfile:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION
ARG PHP_TYPE
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-${PHP_TYPE}-alpine
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
        stage("Build") {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name "PHP_VERSION"
                        values "8.0", "8.1", "8.2"
                    }
                }

                stages {

                    stage('Check version fpm') {
                        agent {
                            docker {
                                image "php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine"
                                reuseNode true
                            }
                        }
                        steps {
                            script {
                                phpversion = sh (
                                script: "php -r 'echo PHP_VERSION;'",
                                returnStdout: true
                                ).trim()
                                echo "${phpversion}"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    stage("Build image") {
                        steps {
                            sh """
                                docker buildx build --target php-fpm --build-arg PHP_TYPE=fpm --build-arg PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION} --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t myrepo/php-fpm:${PHP_VERSION} -t myrepo/php-fpm:${phpversion} --no-cache .
                            """
                        }
                    }
```

I know that is [bug](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67749) in Jenkins but maybe there is another method to do the above steps.

Comment: Add a stage at the start that simply assigns `"php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine"` to a variable, and then change the agent config to `image that_var`. The initial assignment should interpolate the string properly and get around this bug. [Assuming that Jenkins interpolates when defined, rather than when referenced]

Comment: @Sammitch I get: 
+ php:8.0-fpm-alpine
/opt/agent/workspace/test/php-fpm/php-fpm-test@tmp/durable-58125a7a/script.sh: 1: php:8.0-fpm-alpine: not found